# Designing power supply on two sides of the PCB

Tags: pcb-design, switching-regulator

I am beginner in PCB design. I have a reverse voltage regulator LT8365 generating -50V from 24V input, only this design exist on the topside of the PCB(2 layer) and I wanted to add another one(same regulator) on the bottom side of the PCB so to generate another -50V independent rail and not increasing the dimension of the board. So, Can I create a 4 layer board to achieve this? meaning, add one regulator with all it's external components on top side and another identical design on the bottom side? or this is just not possible?

I hope to hear back about your thought on this.

Comment: It is possible, if you made two 2 layer PCBs with components on only one side, then glued the two together (with isolation in between) you'd basically have the same as a 4 layer PCB. The challenge is in mounting the components, to not make the components on side A fall off when side B is populated. But that can be solved, for example by gluing the components to the PCB on one side or soldering by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Designing a board to have components on both sides is very possible. It poses a bit of a challenge on assembly, so it will be more expensive if you let a factory assemble it, or it will be more work if you assemble it yourself.

Couple of things to watch out for:

- power supply chips tend to produce heat. Now you have twice the heat in the same PCB volume, with less area to get rid of it. If this was close to being critical in the one-sided design, you *really* have to re-do your thermal design.
- In a lot of places, you *really* want to make sure the ground below your SMPS works well – so, you'd have to place your components in a way that doesn't break the ground plane in places it matters. This is usually the point where you realize you need to do something else than moving things to the bottom of a 2-layer board and indeed need 4 layers. Which comes at a pretty steep price increase, so maybe look into highly integrated SMPS modules from Texas Instruments or from Murata, which might help you achieve high density without having to switch to 4 layers.
- Not all SMPS components can be operated synchronously, should you wish to just increase the current capacity of the same rail. Your IC indeed can be driven from an external clock, which would facilitate that, but it's still a design effort.

  - If indeed just increasing the current capacity, it might be wiser to look into a larger inductance and if necessary a switch and controller that deal with higher currents.
- If you instead need to generate another, independent, rail, look into multi-output switch-mode regulator controllers. It will probably use less space to use one of these on the top side of your board than having another supply at the bottom, considering that complicates design.

Comment: I have considered using multi output SMPS but there are no such options available to generate negative output although if I were to generate positive rail and then convert it to negative it would need additional and bulky circuits since output voltage is about -50V hence I though of this approach. However the approach @Bimpelrekkie suggested which is by gluing them together would there still be risk of breaking ground planes?

Comment: if you went for 2 layers, a functional ground plane will be hard to impossible to achieve. If you went for 4 layers, sure, no big problem. (it's not "gluing components together"; it's "gluing them to the board, so the top and bottom side can be soldered in one go in an oven"). But you really need to ask yourself what you're winning by going to 4 layers (expensive) and doing bottom side components (expensive, you need a component gluing step after the solder paste application step)  just because you need more current (?) or because you need a second -50V rail (?).

Comment: You'll really want to **edit** your question to include what your constraints are, *why exactly* you want to add another regulator of the same type.

Comment: Thank you very much on the insight, well, I need a second -50V rail. 4 layers is okay. Maybe soldering it in the oven would be a better option than by hand

Comment: if you still feel like soldering it like hand... is there a chance to lay out other parts of your PCB more tightly so that you don't even have to go to the bottom and to get 4 layers?